# I built a monte carlo simulation option pricer in excel. How do i modify it to price american options?

Tags: options, vba

I see several methods to modify the monte carlo model to price american option payoffs. However, the math looks a little too complex to model into excel - i am looking at the least square methods by longstaff and schwartz 2003.

how can this be coded into vba?

Comment: I use this site as the basis for many of my VBAs http://investexcel.net/options-kb/ good luck

Answer (score 1):

How about trying a simple rule for early exercise.  For example , exercise if stock > X, where C could be a constant or a vector.  Chose X to maximize the option value.